# Prove that $ \lim_{x\to0^+}1/x-\lfloor1/x\rfloor$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis

1.lim(x→c) f (x) = L
2.For every sequence (xn) in D/{c} converging to c, we have
lim(n→inf) f(xn) = L.

1 and 2 is equivalent. use the theorem to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two different sequences converging to $0^+$:  $x_n=\frac1n$ and $y_n=\frac1{n+\frac12}$.

The limits $f(x_n)=0$ and $f(y_n)=\frac12$ don't agree.

Comment: limits f(xn) should it be 1? since 1/x is a decreasing function.

Comment: I get $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n-n=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I will think over it.

Comment: I get it, I considered x→1/n before. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n}  $$
$$ b_n = \frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}   $$

Answer (score 0):

for all $\delta > 0$ there exists an integer $q$ such that $\frac {2}{q}$ and $\frac {2}{q+1}$ are greater than $0$ and less than $\delta$

for one of these $f(x) = \frac {1}{2}$  and for the other $f(x) = 0$

Let $\epsilon = \frac 14$

Clearly there is no $L$ such that for all $x \in (0,\delta), |f(x) - L|< \frac 14$